# I cant click on another button after clicking on a first button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am fairly new to Java and android studio, I am building an app and when testing it on the emulator I can click on a button and it will bring up what I programmed it to do but when I go back to the main screen and try click on another button or even the same button I had just clicked, it wont do a thing. I cant seem to find what I missed or if I forgot to add something. I am not getting any errors either.

```
//On Click Listener for all info buttons
final View.OnClickListener mGlobal_OnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.Areainfo:
                Intent area = new Intent(Layout.this, AreaInfo.class);
                startActivity(area);
                //Inform user Areainfo is selected
                Toast.makeText(Layout.this, "Area Info selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.Runinfo:
                Intent run = new Intent(Layout.this, RunInfo.class);
                startActivity(run);
                //Inform user Runinfo is selected
                Toast.makeText(Layout.this, "Run Info selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.Runnuminfo:
                Intent runnum = new Intent(Layout.this, RunNumInfo.class);
                startActivity(runnum);
                //Inform user Runnuminfo is selected
                Toast.makeText(Layout.this, "Number of Runs Info selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.Nmininfo:
                Intent Nmin = new Intent(Layout.this, NminInfo.class);
                startActivity(Nmin);
                //Inform user Nmininfo is selected
                Toast.makeText(Layout.this, "Nmin Info selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.Zvalinfo:
                Intent Zval = new Intent(Layout.this, ZvalInfo.class);
                startActivity(Zval);
                //Inform user Zvalinfo is selected
                Toast.makeText(Layout.this, "Zvals Info selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.Calculate:
                Intent Imperial = new Intent(Layout.this, ImperialCalc.class);
                startActivity(Imperial);
                Toast.makeText(Layout.this, "Calculating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: show your full code ...

Comment: Fixed it @DavidStockinger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove `setContentView` from every `case`

Comment: @Alenander should be correct. Try only calling setContentView() inside the onCreate for Activities and onCreateView for Fragments. There is no reason to inflate the same view outside of those methods (in most cases)

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander suggests you need to remove the `setContentView()` from every case. Only calling this once in `onCreate()` is enough. What goes wrong is that with `setContentView()` your current `View` gets removed, including all your `onClickListener()`. Therefore going back to the `Activity` and pressing a button will not work, since the `onClickListeners()` are gone.